# SNMP octetstring, How do I "decode" it?

Tags: excel, vba, snmp, octetstring

I have a macro that reads the values from all printers at work.
There is one value I just can't decode.

Using this code

```
Set objSNMP = CreateObject("OlePrn.OleSNMP")
objSNMP.Open "10.158.110.8", "public", 2, 10000
Debug.Print objSNMP.get(".1.3.6.1.4.1.641.6.2.3.1.7.1")
```

I get this in the immediate window:

ß
0

[image]

When I use SNMPWalk I get this octetstring:

```
OID=.1.3.6.1.4.1.641.6.2.3.1.7.1, Type=OctetString, Value=  07 DF 06 14 0D 30 0E 00 00 00 00 00
```

From all that I can understand, the value in plain text should be `2015-06-20` since this OID is the date of installation of the machine.
And according to the webUI of the printer that is the date.

[image]

I have tried to find how to decode it using the MIB but I can't find anything about this value.
https://infoserve.lexmark.com/ids/ifc/ids_topic.aspx?root=kb20211110015949938&topic=FA615&productCode=Lexmark_MX410&loc=en_IN

Anyone have any hints on decoding the octetstring?

Comment: Well, (H stands for hex, D for decimal)H `07 DF` = D `2015`, H `06` = D `6`, Hex `14` = Dec `20` IOW as date: 2015-06-20, and H `0D` = D `13`, H `30` = D `48`, H `0E` = D `15` IOW as time: 13:48:15

Answer (score 1):

`OCTET STRING` is only used to pass bytes over the wire. You need to know the actual text convention for `.1.3.6.1.4.1.641.6.2.3.1.7.1` from the MIB document, and that's

```
deviceInstallDate OBJECT-TYPE
    SYNTAX      DateAndTime
    MAX-ACCESS  read-only
    STATUS      current
    DESCRIPTION
        "The install date of the device.  This information should be provided
         by the attached device"
    ::= { deviceEntry 7 }
```

You should decode the data following the rule of `DateAndTime` and I wrote about that in [this article](https://halfblood.pro/snmp-pro-dateandtime-syntax-support-e99abc51bc2f).